How to set ID in Qdrant points in n8n
According to Qdrant documentation when inserting with the same ID, points will be replaced. But in n8n I can't see how I can set up ID for qdrant points. I set id in metadata, but it's not the point id. I need it because every time I insert same document it duplicates.

Afaik, n8n generates IDs under the hood, which I figured out when I did my Qdrant & n8n demo:)
I can advise you to request a feature from them to allow inserting your own id's:)
In the meanwhile, you could use HTTP-request block and call Qdrant's API directly
(P.S. I am Jenny, Qdrant's DevRel, nice to meet you:) )
